# How to build a skeleton engine with Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-physics

I want to develop a game. It would draw a stick man, and edit his pose.

I think what I need to learn are **bones animation** and **physical engine**.

Anyone can introduce good resources to learn both?

---

edit1:

My question may be ambiguous because of the bone tool of the Flash Professional.
What I mean is a as3 framework which add a skeleton to a game character.

Comment: Why have you asked this on both SO and gamedev SE?

Answer (score 1):

Might be of help:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-flash-professional-cs5/using-spring-properties-with-ik-bones

Comment: Sorry, my question may be ambiguous. What I mean is a as3 framework which add a skeleton to a game avatar. Not the flash professional tool.